# Graph API & Real-Time updates

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph, updates, real-time-updates

My need is to have facebook poll my server using POST requests whenever a user that has "allowed / installed" my application changes something, eg, their checkins.

I have followed the page at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime very thoroughly and have successfully set up the subscription.

When I place a get request the subscriptions graph I get the below response.

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "object": "user",
     "callback_url": "http://www.HIDDEN.com/FORSECURITY/callback.php",
     "fields": [
        "checkins",
        "feed"
     ],
     "active": true
  }
   ]
}
```

Which tells me that the subscription is set up, and that when a user that has authenticated my app, changes their feed / checkins, that a POST request should be sent to the callback_url.

The problem is, it does not. I have Googled, troubleshooted, Googled some more, redid everything and I just can't seem to find the answer.

I have tested my callback.php file by posting to it, and it captured all the data, I just capture everything in $_POST to make sure if there is anything that I will capture it.

I've also added if statements to just write to a file if the file is accessed and !empty($_POST)

I tried checking in, making wall posts everything. It just does not poll the callback php.

Does anyone have an Idea about this?

Thanks. 
Mandus

*UPDATE*

It seems like after 60 minutes, it started working. So it probably takes a while for everything to get activated.

Comment: I suggest adding your eventual results as an answer once you're allowed to -- it might help someone else discover this problem in the future.

Comment: Will Do. I am busy finishing the system, will post a full explanation of everything once it's finished.